# Does the depth of a lake affect how quickly its water is evaporated?

Tags: water, phase

Suppose there are two freshwater lakes, each with identical surface areas and circumferences. One lake is 1 ft deep and the other is 20 ft deep. Although they exist in nature, lets assume they are both exposed to the same identical climate and sunlight. Will the difference in depth affect in any way affect the rate of evaporation of the water? Will one of the lakes lost 1 inch of water to evaporation faster?

Comment: The problem posed has no simple answer. Rates of evaporation would depend on a number of factors such as thermal layers in the water, heat exchange between between water and ground, and so forth.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  Generally answerers prefer is some effort is first made by the questioners.

Comment: You should consider what is different between the bodies of water in terms of thermal transport by conduction and convection. A shallower body will probably reach higher temperatures, accelerating evaporation.

Comment: This is not a chemistry question. Also for a thought experiment, it is far too unspecific.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about chemistry.

Comment: @Karl  Agreed, the question lacks needed specifics.  But questions about evaporation rates and what affect them fall well within the purview of physical chemistry, and thus of this site.

Answer (score 2):

The evaporation of water does not depend on the depth of the lake. It depends on the temperature and of the wind. Here are some values, valid for a lake of infinitive surface, with an "usual humidity"

At $10°$C, the level of the water decreases by $0.9$ mm/day if the wind is zero, by $1.2$ mm/day with a $2$ m/s wind, and by $1.7$ mm/day with a $9$ m/s wind

At $20°$C, those values are respectively $3.2$ mm/day, $4.5$ mm/day and $6.1$ mm/day, when the wind blows at $0$ m/s, $2$ m/s and $9$ m/s.

At $30°$C, the same values are respectively $6.8$ mm/day, $9.6$ mm/day, $12.9$ mm/day, when the wind blows at $0$ m/s, $2$ m/s and $9$ m/s.

If the lake is not on sea level, these values should be multiplied by ($\ce{1 + 1.08 10^{-4} h}$), if h is the height above sea level, in meter.

The present values are average values, calculated for an "average" humidity. They change with the relative humidity or the water pressure in a complicated way, with empirical parameters which would take too long to be developed here. It also changes with the dimensions of the lake. I have only given the values for an infinite surface.

Other values are given for sea water in oceans.

These values are taken from a book by M. Dorsey, Properties of the Water Substance, Reinhold Co., New York 1940.

Comment: Thanks for the values, Maurice, the data can be widely useful. But temperature of the surface water depends on the lake depth. E.g. the lake bed of the lake 1ft deep would be warmed up by the direct sunlight, while the one of 20 ft deep not. There will be convection and overall warming up of the shallow lake. The Sun light will effectively warm up thinner water layer. So IMHO the evaporation rate depends on the depth indirectly.

Comment: Seems either M. Dorsey was optimistic about simplicity of the problem, or you didn't mention all his assumptions of what else has to be constant to get these values - and that's a lot of things.

Comment: @Mithoron. I should have mentioned that the values from my previous message are average values, calculated for an "average" humidity. They change with the relative humidity or the water pressure in a complicated way. There are a lot of empirical parameters which would take too long to be developed here. Why don't you open M. Dorsey's book ? It also changes with the dimensions of the lake. I have only given the values for an infinite surface.

Comment: Well, then edit this in your post. BTW I can hardly open it as it was first time I even heard about it...

Comment: M. Dorsey's book is in the library archives of my University ... I have discovered it by a bit of luck !

Comment: You haven't considered other factors.  For instance, evaporation cools the water, and a foot-deep lake will be more cooled during the evaporation of an inch of water than a deeper lake, thus causing this evaporation to be slower.  In addition, fresh water has dissolved solutes, reducing its vapor pressure, and this vapor pressure will be more reduced during evaporation from a shallower lake because the concentration of those solutes will increase more rapidly in the latter case, thus also causing reduced evaporation rate in the shallow lake.  etc. etc.

Comment: @theorist. The temperature is taken in the water, not in the air. In a shallow lake its temperature will decrease, and the evaporation will decrease, according to the numerical values from Dorsey. And fresh water does contain solutes of course, but in negligible amounts. You probably have noticed that the reported numerical values have only two significant figures. They are averages, which are not precise. You know. A rough result is better than no result at all.

Comment: @Maurice  As evaporation proceeds, the water temp in both the shallow and deep lake will decrease, but it will decrease more in the shallow lake, causing the evaporation rate in the shallow lake to decrease faster than that in the deeper lake, causing it to take longer.  That's considering just that one factor.

Comment: Freshly formed shallow pools of water evaporate rapidly also because it is  largely freshwater (seawater has lower levels of evaporation).